# how to use triangular as front end for spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gulp, bower

I want to use triangular as a front end for my spring boot web app .

the problem is that they using gulp, bower and it runs on different port so how can i manage this for my spring boot app back end, and manage the dependencies of the front end.

[triangular site](http://themeforest.net/item/triangular-material-design-admin-template-angularjs/11711437)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? => [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Maven Frontend Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)

This plugin allows you to harness the power of the Node.js ecosystem including Gulp, Bower & much more.

Examples:

- [JHipster Sample App](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app)
- [Spring Boot + Maven Frontend Plugin](https://github.com/mikaelhg/spring-boot-webpack-es6-react-poc)
- [React.js + Spring Data REST](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest)

The aforementioned applications each use the plugin differently.  It supports a wide variety of configurations.  My preference is putting all my frontend code into src/main/frontend and directing the output to the **target** directory.